# Upper bounds on the norm of a matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, inequality, exponential-function, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a non-negative matrix and let $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a signature matrix, i.e. a diagonal matrix having either $+ 1$ or $-1$ elements on its diagonal. Notice that it holds $D=D^{-1}$. Consider the matrix
$$
B:=AD.
$$
Observe that $B$ is equal to $A$ except for the fact that some of its columns may have opposite sign.

> **The problem.** I'm interested in some estimates of the 2-norm of the matrix exponential of $B$. In particular, I'm wondering whether it's possible to derive upper bounds on $\|\exp (B)\|_2$ of the form
>   $$
> \|\exp (B)\|_2\leq f(A,D)\|\exp(A)\|_2,
> $$
>   for some function $f$ of $A$ and/or $D$. Any suggestions?

**Note 1.** Using the subadditivity and submultiplicativity of matrix 2-norm, we can obtain the bound
$$
\|\exp (B)\|_2\leq \exp(\|A\|_2).
$$
However, this bound is quite loose and not very informative.

**Note 2.** It can be assumed that $A$ is symmetric, if that helps in deriving a bound.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do any better than note 1.  Since $A$ is symmetric, you can express that 2-norm in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Is your 2-norm the operator norm (the "spectral norm") or the Frobenius norm?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: The operator norm. However, if it's possible to derive a bound for the Frobenius norm, I'm interested in it as well.

Comment: I think if you want any kind of improvement to your inequality, you'll have to say something about the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Alternatively, if we partition the matrix $B$ in the form $$ \begin{bmatrix}A_{11} &-A_{12} \\ A_{21} &-A_{22}  \end{bmatrix},$$ is it possible to derive a bound on $\|\exp(B)\|_2$ using the norm of the exp of the diagonal blocks?

Comment: that does give us a *little* more information, but I have a feeling that the answer is no: there's always a worst-case that occurs when one of the eigenvectors of $A$ is a standard basis vector.